# How to make a series of items

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit

I'm working on a Spritekit game for iOS7, and I want to have a series of coins falling down the screen from top to bottom. I am familiar with the fact that to have a series of items, an array is usually preferred but I am not to familiar with arrays. To make the coins fall constantly, this is what I have set up:

```
-(void)testCoins {

    testCoin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"catCoin.png"] size:CGSizeMake(26.05, 25.5)];
    testCoin.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:12];
    testCoin.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    testCoin.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionDebris;
    testCoin.name = @"coin";

    RandomPosition = arc4random() %260*DoubleIfIpad;
    RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 20*DoubleIfIpad;
    testCoin.position = CGPointMake (RandomPosition, self.size.height + 40*DoubleIfIpad);

    [self addChild:testCoin];

    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-self.size.height+100 duration:10.0];

    [testCoin runAction:moveDown];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
            [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0],
            [SKAction performSelector:@selector(testCoins) onTarget:self],
    ]]];

    if (testCoin.position.y < CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)) {
        [testCoin removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, and the coins spawn properly and flow down the screen properly. The problem actually lies within the contact, because the if statement I used for contact tells the program to remove the coin, then add a point. This does so, but it always keeps one coin on the screen and does not remove it, but instead if the player continues to tap on the visible coin, it will add points, and remove the other coins from the screen. I think this is because I am using a `performSelector` call to keep repeating the method, so it is keeping one coin on the screen. Although I could be wrong, I'm completely confused.

Is there a better way to be doing this? Maybe extra methods for extra coins???

If anyone has made something similar, could you please guide me in the right direction, be it adding an array etc.

Thanks in advance, if any extra info is needed please let me know.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the scope of your testCoin reference. It should probably be defined inside the testCoins method if you are going to be running it recursively.

Comment: If you aren't comfortable with arrays then you have some studying to do. Arrays are a foundational building block of most languages and putting off understanding them is denying yourself a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its easy sprite kit provide us a unique method to search node my name " enumerateChildNodesWithName "

just check out the example below i think its work for you and you don't need a array for that

```
#import "milkhuntMyScene.h"

@implementation milkhuntMyScene
{
    int balloonId;
    int aniId;
    int removeId;
}
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        [self FallBalloons:20];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)FallBalloons:(int)total
{
    for(int i=0;i<total;i++)
    {
        balloonId+=1;
        SKSpriteNode *balloon=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"balloon1.png"];
        [self addChild:balloon];
        balloon.position=CGPointMake(50+(i*balloon.size.width), 700);
        balloon.name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balloon%d", balloonId];
    }
    SKAction *aniTime= [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                [SKAction waitForDuration:0.2],
                                                [SKAction performSelector:@selector(aniBalloon)
                                                                 onTarget:self]

                                                ]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:aniTime count:total]];
}
-(void)aniBalloon
{
            aniId+=1;
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balloon%d", aniId] usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction moveToY:50 duration:1]];
        SKAction *removeTime= [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                [SKAction waitForDuration:1.1],
                                                [SKAction performSelector:@selector(removeBalloon)
                                                                 onTarget:self]

                                                ]];
        [self runAction:removeTime];
    }];
}

-(void)removeBalloon
{
    removeId+=1;
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balloon%d", removeId] usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }];

}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

   }

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```